# change href value in different function

Tags: jquery

let say i have the following html and jquery script:

//html script

```
<a href="http://tr.abc.com/?id=qwe&media=34567" class="getitnow" id="prod123"></a>
<a href="http://tr.abc.com/?id=qwe&media=34567" class="getitnow" id="prod456"></a>
<a href="http://tr.abc.com/?id=qwe&media=34567" class="getitnow" id="prod789"></a>
```

//JQUERY script

```
   $(".getitnow").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        checklogin(this);

    });

    function checklogin(el) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
       statusChangeCallback(response, el);
    });


    }


function statusChangeCallback(response, el){

//process the el
    console.log($(el).attr('href));
    changeEL(el);
    console.log($(el).attr('href));

window.open( $(el).attr('href) );

}


    function changeEL(el){

    var newURL = $(el).attr('href') + "&prm1=234&prm2=kjh";
    $(el).attr('href', newURL);

    }
```

Both console.log() are returning same value which is the old href value.
I want the window.open opening the current URL + newURL which is processed in changeEL function.
What happen in this case is that it open the original URL which is the http://tr.abc.com/?id=qwe&media=34567

I am expecting the el object passed to changeEL would have changed/updated, but it doesn't seem that is the case.

How can i get the window.open to open as http://tr.abc.com/?id=qwe&media=34567http://tr.abc.com/?id=qwe&media=34567

Comment: you are not passing the second parameter to statusChangeCallback. You call statusChangeCallback(this) but the function expects a second parameter 'el'. Might it be a problem?

Comment: oh sorry, actually i am using FB app. the response comes from FB app.let me restructure my code..

Comment: The FB response is definitely got value.